Mosaicking hyperspectral images with band averaging over overlapping areas
I'm trying to use gdal.Warp to mosaic hyperspectral images with overlapping boundaries, but want to be able to do so while getting the average values of pixels within these overlapping ranges. The solution for this that I've seen so far has been to use gdal.Translate with VRT pixel functions, but most of these solutions have been geared towards 1-band images. My images have >200 bands. How would I go about doing this with GDAL? Are there better open source tools I should look into?

If they are not too big to fit in RAM/memory*, you could use rasterio.merge.merge with sum and count operators and calculate mean from sum/count.
Example
I have three partially overlapping test datasets, each with 10 bands. input1.tif contains only 1's as pixel values, input2.tif contains 2's and input3.tif contains 3's.
If I mosaic them, I would expect to get the input values (i.e 1,2 & 3) where they don't overlap, 1.5 where input1.tif and input2.tif overlap and so on for other average values and NoData where no valid pixels overlap.
gdalinfo -stats input1.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: input1.tif
Size is 2596, 1678
Origin = (-1505188.094100000103936,-3592640.986399999819696)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
...
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=1.000, Mean=1.000, StdDev=0.000
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
...
Band 10 Block=256x256 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=1.000, Mean=1.000, StdDev=0.000
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_MEAN=1
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100


Code
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.merge import merge
import numpy as np

inputs = ["input1.tif", "input2.tif", "input3.tif"]

inputs = [rio.open(i, masked=True) for i in inputs]
profile = inputs[0].profile.copy()
nodata = np.finfo("float32").min

merged_count, merged_transform = merge(inputs, method="count")
merged_sum, merged_transform = merge(inputs, method="sum")

profile.update(
    driver="GTIFF",
    dtype="float32",  # inputs are integer and the mean can be non-int and I don't want to truncate
    transform=merged_transform,
    count=merged_count.shape[0],
    height=merged_count.shape[1],
    width=merged_count.shape[2],
    nodata=nodata
)
mask = merged_count == 0
merged_mean = merged_sum/merged_count
merged_mean[mask] = nodata
with rio.open("output.tif", "w", **profile) as output:
    output.write(merged_mean)

Output

* If they are too big to fit in memory, an upcoming version of rasterio (2.0?) will include a mem_limit argument to process in chunks.

Oh wow that's great! Thanks for the detailed answer!

@monicaJ If it works on your data, you could upvote and accept the answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
